# SQL synchronize database between local and remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server, synchronization

I've got 2 companies in different locations and the main server is at my office. The main server is working with a full version of SQL Server where the companies use SQL Server express version.

What is the best way to synchronize these SQL Server databases together that the main server have always the latest updates?

Answer (score 3):

There are several technologies specifically for this type of scenario:

- [SQL Replication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx)

  - Supports unidirectional or bidirectional synchronization
- [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)

  - Lets you define the mappings of the data, as well as transformations, and attach other code to the process easily
- [Linked-servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

  - Allows you to query databases and tables on remote servers as though they are part of the local database.  Very easy to setup (just call `exec sp_addlinkedserver`) and once defined uses nothing but plain old SQL

If you want to do in an event (like button click), I would suggest `Linked Server`. [Click here](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/how-to-add-sql-server-linked-server.aspx) for a simple tutorial about how to create a linked server. After creating linked server, we can query it as follows:

```
select * from LinkedServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName
```